# Rails - How to delegate method to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates, rails-activestorage

I am using ActiveStorage for file uploads via API. My "File" model is namespaced under "Loot", so it is "Loot::Files". The File model has an association (ActiveStorage) "has_many_attached :files".

## User.rb

```
has_many :files, class_name: 'Loot::File'
```

## loot/file.rb (Loot::File)

```
has_many_attached :files
```

While this works (i can call user.files.files) it's really ugly and awkward to call files on files.

Is there a way to keep the namespace "Loot" but only need to call user.files to access the ActiveStorage files? I tried using delegate but it seems it doesn't work delegating to collections.

Update: I tried the following delegate

### Try 1

User.rb

```
delegate :files, to: "Loot::File"
```

With that, calling "User.first.files", i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):3
    1: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
NoMethodError (undefined method `files' for Loot::File(id: integer, user_id: integer):Class)
```

### Try 2

User.rb

```
delegate :files, to: :files
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   16: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   15: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   14: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   13: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   12: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   11: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
   10: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    9: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    8: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    7: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    6: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    5: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    4: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    3: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    2: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
    1: from app/models/user.rb:46:in `files'
SystemStackError (stack level too deep)
```

### Try 3 - Renaming

I tried renaming Loot::Files to Loot:Uploads and using the following delegate

User.rb

```
delegate :files, to: :uploads
```

but then i get the following when calling User.first.files

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `files' for #<Loot::Upload::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fdb96ca91c0>)
```

Comment: Can you post your delegate code? I'm surprised that didn't work. Other than that, you can just make your own method on User that returns `files.files`. Also, I'd consider renaming one of these - not good to have that ambiguity, and maybe that's what broke the delegate.

Comment: I updated the post with the delegate i tried. If i make my own method i need to use that explicitly while i would prefer to just call it the standard way and have it work everywhere without the need  to call a custom method.. if that makes sense.

Do you have a suggestion for the naming pattern? I was thinking of files.uploads maybe?

Comment: Your delegate should be `delegate :method, :to: :other_method`, not, `to: class_name`. Try `delegate :files, to: :files`. What the delegate means is that the "other_method" should be called, then call "method" on it.

Comment: Thanks i tried that as well before but also got the above error. Just updated the post again

Comment: You're getting a stack overflow error, because the two method names are the same. User is calling files which is told to call files, but when files it's called, it's supposed to call files, which calls files, which is supposed to call files, etc. The problem can be solved by renaming one of these items so they're not the same name.

Comment: I just tried that but i get the error in try 3, updated above.

Comment: Does it still have `has_many_attached :files`? Don't rename that part if you've already named that file.

Comment: Yes it still has the has_many_attached :files. The problem is that it is calling .files on a collection but it can only be called on a single record

Answer (score 1):

How about using `through` and renaming the files association eg:

User:

```
has_many :loot_files, class_name: 'Loot::File'
has_many :files, through: :loot_files
```

You should then be able to use:

```
user.loot_files.files
user.files
```